# How to connect to NodeJS server with Ngnix proxy?

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

I have patched the nignx with `nginx_tcp_proxy_module`.

So i wanna to connect to `http://domainname/activity`, which will be forwarded to NodeJS!

I noticed an exception when had the following test:

```
var socket = new io.Sockect("http://localhost/activity");
```

the client made a wrong request like this:

Request URL: `http://http//domainname/activity:80/socket.io/xhr-polling//1312776194995`

Anybody can tell me what is wrong?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Not unless you tell us your nginx config...

Comment: Addition location /activity{proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;} others config as normal!

Comment: And i have put up and TCP server like : http://www.letseehere.com/about-johnathan-leppert

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost/activity');
```

instead of new io.Socket(...);

You can find more informations at the [Socket.io](http://socket.io/)  Page.

Comment: Yes, now connection method in the socket.io-7 is available. but how to forward request to nodejs from nginx?

Comment: I have patched nginx_tcp_proxy_module, however , how to forward the request to nginx with tcp{} section?